# Angular JS Route not working (Simple Example)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm beginner with AngularJS and try to use routes, but due to some reason its not working and special characters are also appearing in URL.
Files are below:

**Index.html**

```
<html ng-app="myRouteApp" lang="ens">
    <head>
        <title>Angular Route Project</title>
        <script src="../js/angular.js"></script>
        <script src="../js/angular-route.js"></script>
        <script src="../js/script2.js"></script>
        <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <table style="Font-Family: Arial;">
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2" class="header">
                    <h1>WEBSITE HEADER</h1>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="leftMenu">
                    <a href="#/home">Home</a>
                    <a href="#/courses">Courses</a>
                    <a href="#/students">Students</a>
                </td>
                <td class="mainContent">
                    <ng-view></ng-view>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2" class="footer">
                    <h5>WEBSITE FOOTER</h5>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

**script2.js**

```
var app = angular.module("myRouteApp", ["ngRoute"])
                .config(function($routeProvider){
                    $routeProvider
                    .when("/home",{
                                templateUrl: "templates/home.html",
                                controller: "homeController"
                            })
                    .when("/courses",{
                                templateUrl: "templates/courses.html",
                                controller: "coursesController"
                            })
                    .when("/students",{
                                templateUrl: "templates/students.html",
                                controller: "studentsController"
                            })
                })
        .controller("homeController", function($scope){
            $scope.message = "Home Page";
        })
        .controller("coursesController", function($scope){
            $scope.courses = ["PHP", "JAVA", "C#", "C"];
        })
        .controller("studentsController", function($scope){
            $scope.students = ["ALI", "Usama", "Usman", "Omer"];
        })
```

All code I'm using same as tutorial but don't know what's the error! Help will be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: What is the exact error?

Comment: "ngRoute" is not working and URL is like
file:///C:/Users/SHARY%20MALIK/Desktop/Angular%20JS/Files/project/index.html#!/#%2Fcourses

Answer (score 3):

By default `hashPrefix` is `!` in `ngRoute`, so your all URL should have `!` inside their URL's. That means your URL's should have `#!/` inspite of `#/` only.

```
<td class="leftMenu">
    <a href="#!/home">Home</a>
    <a href="#!/courses">Courses</a>
    <a href="#!/students">Students</a>
</td>
```

---

Better way would be completely get rid of `!` from URL. You need to set `hashPrefix` to `''`(empty) using `$locationProvider` inside config phase of application.

```
app.config(['$locationProvider', function($locationProvider){
   $locationProvider.hashPrefix('');
}])
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, ! is disappear after adding $locationProvider.hashPrefix('');
But ngRoute is still not working. Is there some problem in my system?